# Как правильно построить виджет в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import urllib.request

class ImgPost(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, login, img, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent=parent)

    self.post = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(img).read()
    self.pixmap = QPixmap()
    self.pixmap.loadFromData(data)
    self.login = QtWidgets.QLabel(f'<a href="https://www.instagram.com/{login}">{login}</a>')
    self.login.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
    self.images = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    #self.images.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
    self.images.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
    self.post.addWidget(self.login)
    self.post.addWidget(self.images)
    self.img = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.img.setLayout(self.post)
```

На выходе добавляю это в QVBoxLayout с QScrollArea
Получаю :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать изображения во всю ширину?

Comment: `Как сделать изображения во всю ширину?` на всю ширину QScrollArea? Изображения ведь некрасиво расширятся в разы. Вы хотите в один столбец (списком) разместить картинки?

Answer (score 0):

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import urllib.request

class ImgPost(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, login, img, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent=parent)

    self.post = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(img).read()
    self.pixmap = QPixmap()
    self.pixmap.loadFromData(data)
    self.login = QtWidgets.QLabel(f'<a href="https://www.instagram.com/{login}">{login}</a>')
    self.login.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
    self.images = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    #self.images.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
    self.images.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
    self.post.addWidget(self.login,10,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.post.addWidget(self.images,10,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.img = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.img.setLayout(self.post)
```

Получил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это уточнение кода в вопросе? Если да, то под вопросом есть кнопка `править`, туда и нужно добавить код, а этот `ответ` удалить )

Comment: @gil9red это ответ

Comment: Наличие `QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter` ведь не увеличивает изображение на всю ширину, а это единственное различие с кодом в ответе

Comment: @gil9red если вы моете предложить другое решения я весь во внимании

Comment: Я бы рад предложить, но непонятно что вы хотите. Уточняющий вопрос под вашим вопросом (хех) в комментарии задавал. А так, мне кажется, в вашем примере нужно все `ImgPost` под один размер подогнать, например как плитки 200x200.

Comment: Пытаюсь сделать что то подобное ленты инстаграм , щас получил более хороший результат , поправил ответ выше